# Implement dependency injection if using third party dll

Tags: c#, dependency-injection

In my MVC5 web application I am using dependency injection. But here for login and related functionalities I am using a existing dll and calling method in that dll. Now I am creating object of that class and calling corresponding method.  can I implement dependency injection here, since I don't have Interface for this class

For example
I am referring a dll named MyCompany.Authenticate in my application
for login I am creating object of a class in that dll and calling login method in that class
i.e

```
WebAuthenticationClass obj =new WebAuthenticationClass(); 
obj.login(username,pwd);
```

this is what I am doing now. I need to change the new object creation to dependency injection.

Comment: Please supply some concrete code to your question. Without some code the question is too broad.

Comment: @Steven updated with code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not all dependencies in your code need to be abstracted away. But if you determined that the dependency on `MyCompany.Authenticate` or `WebAuthenticationClass` is unwanted from within your code, you should place it behind an abstraction.

It doesn't matter that `WebAuthenticationClass` does not implement an abstraction, because such abstraction will typically be useful. The abstraction/interface must be defined by the consumer and must be specific to to the consumer's needs. Abstractions defined by the 3rd party tool are usually useless, because they are generic and tailored for the library itself. And don't forget that when using the library's abstractions, you still depend upon t hat library.

So what you should do is:

1. define an abstraction in your own application that your code can depend upon
2. create an implementation (adapter) that implements your interface and calls into the `WebAuthenticationClass`.

Do note that this interface can have a completely different method signature than the `WebAuthenticationClass` has. Again: define the interface in a way that is most useful for your application, even if that makes the adapter harder to implement.

Comment: so, in interface implementation class I need to do below call
WebAuthenticationClass obj =new WebAuthenticationClass(); 
obj.login(username,pwd);
Right?

Comment: @dmkausu: I don't understand your question. Can you rephrase that?

Comment: so, in interface implementation class I need to do below call WebAuthenticationClass obj =new WebAuthenticationClass(); obj.login(username,pwd); 
Right?

Answer (score 0):

I tend to use Castle Windsor and I know that it will handle this. I assume most other IoC frameworks would too. Make your class accept a `WebAuthenticationClass` as a dependency and then register the type from the other assembly. That should be all you need.